# I would like cost saving and performance options for my e-com site, moving to AWS, that uses XSLT, PHP, and SQL Server 2008r2

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, xslt, amazon-web-services

A little background so as to make this clear.

I have an e-commerce site that has several products that practically never change. I am currently keeping all the information in a SQL Server 2008 database as Rows/Columns. I am exporting on demand the product search information in response to user clicks and the product profile information in XML to be converted by XSLT backed by PHP.

I recently signed up for the free-tier Amazon Web Services. My EC2 instance is hitting a brick wall in terms of performance and memory because of SQL Server bloat. I would like to move to MySQL but the feature set seems behind what I want to do for the needed RDBMS features I currently use. -- but that is another post on how I can get away from MS --

My optimal scenario would be for me to minimize db usage; read, update xml directly from the filesystem or S3; provide the same services to the customer of search and buy what you want; minimize my cost while escaping associated db costs.

I am on a limited budget, hence the free-tier usage. I am very open to any performance tips you may offer aside from what I have asked!

My questions are:

1. Namely is it crazy to not use the built-in XML parser that is part
   of the RDBMS?
2. Is it possible to search XML using like or set conditions with PHP?
   I have products that have genre, product type, brand, and other
   metadata that the user may choose to search by OR can type a free
   text search. **I admit I have not used PHP for XQuery tasks.**
3. If I were to export as XML all my products, how could I keep
   versioned copies if I do make changes? Right at this moment, I
   update a log that shows which changes have been applied, and how
   many times the product has been viewed.
4. What information should I absolutely should keep in the database? I
   was imagining only keeping the productid, upc, price, quantity, and
   enough information to link related items in the database.
5. If I were able to use PHP XQuery to accomplish this, and I were to
   use a lookup XML file, does it matter how I structure the file in
   terms of performance? Say I have
   root->genres->sci-fi->productid/name vs.
   products->product[@genre,@type,@price].
6. Is there an efficient way to represent related items in XML?

Let me know if you need me to elaborate!

Thanks

Comment: Here's the major question. Whats considered in your price range? There are many options available on EC2 but generally speaking there are other providers who will host a website like yours for a much cheaper price. Amazon is very full featured and very cost effective when setting up large installations but with the smaller ones sometimes another provider will be cheaper.

Comment: At the moment. Free is best! I am taking advantage of the free 12 month period before I go elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

For an e-commerce site, using micro instances is a very poor choice. Writing I/O performance is going to be abysmal and you're likely to be hitting  memory limit for micro instance very quickly if you try to use php/mysql/apache/caching etc. Besides, it's only going to be free for a year anyway. In my opinion, you'll be better off migrating your database to mysql and finding decent shared hosting for $5-$10/month.

Comment: I have had experience with Go Daddy for both a VPS and a dedicated server, simply awful and a nightmare. I do not want to have the road blocks of a shared host, i.e lack of PHP controls and not being able to use mod_security. As far as MySQL is concerned, I already posted a request for help in determining if I could move to MySQL. It does not seem to support the basic uses I have.

Comment: I am sorry to disappoint, but you shouldn't expect smooth sailing with  AWS either. That is not to say AWS is bad (or that GoDaddy is good), my company uses AWS pretty extensively and it works well in many scenarios, but using micro instances for e-commerce site just isn't one of them.

Comment: I appreciate that, but it is a start right? Your company probably makes a million a day, and I am trying to launch a simple store that will scale with growth. When the business starts to sell products, that is when I grow to small, medium, and large right?

Comment: Absolutely, especially if you want to learn new technologies along the  way (which I suspect might be the case here :-)), then go for it.